# Offcanvas button has the wrong behavior

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-5

I'm using the latest Bootstrap version of Offcanvas. It has a close button (the offcanvas cannot closed without it). When I click the button `Add to cart` the offcanvas works, but the button `Add to cart` becomes lighter and I can click it (that's not supposed to work, it must be disabled). When I click on it, it behaves as a close button and the canvas closes! How do I fix this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="product-button-group">
  <a class="product-like-icon" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
  </a>
  <button class="add-to-cart" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop" aria-controls="staticBackdrop">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i>ADD TO CART
    </button>

  <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" data-bs-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" id="staticBackdrop" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel">

    <div class="offcanvas-header">
      <h3 class="offcanvas-title">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i> Shopping Cart
      </h3>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="offcanvas-body">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="" alt="mutlu cat shop" width="100px" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h6>Zanies® Twice as Nice Mice</h6>
            <div class="price"><span>$30.00</span> $20.00</div>
            <input class="product-qty" type="number" name="product-qty" min="0" max="10" value="1">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="hr-cart">
      <a class="complete-shopping position-absolute bottom-0 end-0" href="#">   Complete shopping</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="product-compare-icon" href="#"><i class="fas fa-random"></i></a>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your problem isn't clear from what you've shown us. The demo above seems to work fine. Please revise as needed. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a script tag at the top or bottom of the page:

```
<script>
document.querySelector('.add-to-cart').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link action
    // Optionally add your logic here
});
</script>
```

`document.querySelector('.add-to-cart')` is to catch the button by his ID

In the script section, a listener was added to the click event on the "Add to cart" button and the function that drives the action of clicking the link receives the event event. This addition prevents the auto-response of the link and therefore the offcanvas will not open.

Comment: I tried its the same :(